# How to write a Mockito test for a method which calls another method with an unknown argument?

Tags: java, mockito

I have the following method to write a test for:

```
public QuiltResponse create(QuiltRequest quiltRequest, MultipartFile image) throws IOException {
   String fileNameUuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
   saveImage(image, fileNameUuid);
   Quilt newQuilt = quiltFactory.create(quiltRequest, fileNameUuid);
   return new QuiltResponse(quiltRepository.save((newQuilt)), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

I understand why my test won't work: I can't mix up the mocks and the anyString()s.  I really want to replace anyString() with the fileNameUuid as generated within the create() method I am trying to test.  Is this possible?  Thanks!

```
@Test
    void shouldPassToConfirmCreateCallsCorrectUnderlyingMethods() throws IOException {
        QuiltRequest mockQuiltRequest = mock(QuiltRequest.class);
        MultipartFile mockImage = mock(MultipartFile.class);
        QuiltFactory mockQuiltFactory = mock(QuiltFactory.class);
        DefaultQuiltService mockQuiltService = mock(DefaultQuiltService.class);

        mockQuiltService.create(mockQuiltRequest, mockImage);

        verify(mockQuiltService).saveImage(mockImage, anyString());
        verify(mockQuiltFactory).create(mockQuiltRequest, anyString());
    }
```

Comment: To start with, you are calling `create()` on a mocked instance of `DefaultQuiltService`. You should create a real instance, with all its __dependencies__ mocked. Besides this, I would use an `ArgumentCaptor` (https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/ArgumentCaptor.html) to capture the call you want to verify. You can then verify that the method was invoked with a __valid__ UUID. You don't really care what the exact UUID is, right?

Comment: Either inject a `Supplier<UUID>` (and in your test just pass `() -> expectedUuid`), or better, refactor so that you aren't doing multiple parallel operations _in a Web controller method_ (instead, you should have a `QuiltService` that takes care of creating _and_ saving the quilt, and your `saveImage` probably ought to be on a service object as well).

Comment: You can't use actual fileNameUuid as it is generated randomly and it will not be equal to with other generated one during test execution. One solution is to accept it as an argument

Comment: Refactoring it is, then.
Magnilex - thank you for the advice about using a real instance.  I am very, very new to writing test code so your pointer is jolly helpful.
chrysalis - after reflecting on your thoughts I now have a shiny new FileService :)
The test I was trying to write is now very simple.  Cheers, guys!

Answer (score 0):

You need use Powermock

```
import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.mockStatic;
@PrepareForTest({UUID.class})
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public void yourTestMethod(){
  mockStatic(UUID.class);
  when(UUID.randomUUID()).thenReturn("your-UUID");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can

1. Use the Powermock library. https://github.com/powermock/powermock
2. And that one is better as I think (powermock is slow)
   Create a class which will be called in your service, for example UidProvider, create an instance method in it, inject it to he testable code, mock it with regular mockito, that will make your test way faster, and the code more SOLID.

Your production code will look like that:

```
public QuiltResponse create(QuiltRequest quiltRequest, MultipartFile image) throws IOException {
   String fileNameUuid = uidProvider.getUid();
   saveImage(image, fileNameUuid);
   Quilt newQuilt = quiltFactory.create(quiltRequest, fileNameUuid);
   return new QuiltResponse(quiltRepository.save((newQuilt)), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

You can then easily mock the behaviour of your uid generation logic, and not add additional dependencies, and not make your tests slow because of the static mocking.